# blood chemistry of blue-skinned elven race

Tags: xenobiology

If you were to discover blue-skinned humanoids, whose blue blood is bioluminescent turquoise blue, based on silver colloid, could one use the idea that they are germanium based lifeforms?

Would their smooth blue hairless bodies be made of soft tissues like humans, or instead hard like silicon lifeforms ?

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Your question has many issues: first, you are asking about fictional creatures without any constrain, so any answer will be solely based on opinions. Second, you are asking too many different questions in one post. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to understand our standards.